# laravel 8 multiple array value by the index

Tags: arrays, laravel, laravel-8

i have 2 array, and all i want is multiple array value by index, example `0=> 1 * 0=>100000` , `1=> 2 * 1=>90000`, etc. Is that possible ?

array 1 :

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => 1
  1 => 2
 next value ...
]
```

array 2 :

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => 100000
  1 => 90000
 next value ...
]
```

very grateful if someone helps.

Comment: I dont understand example, 1*0 is not 100000

Comment: its index, the index is 0, value is 1 and 100000

Comment: ( 0=> ) its index ,etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $arr1 = [0 => 1, 1 => 2];
    $arr2 = [0 => 100000, 1 => 90000];
    foreach ($arr1 as $k => $val) {
        $total[$k]=$val * $arr2[$k];
    }
```

`$total` will return list of multiplied value, I assumed `$arr2` and `$arr1` has same key count.

Comment: @Reynaldo , if you think this is helpful , please vote and accept my answer, thanks